# MySQL Left Join Query with WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems outputting the data I require:

```
$start_of_month = mktime(00, 00, 00, date('m'), 01);
$datestart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$start_of_month);

'SELECT
orderheader.ordernumber
, ccilog.sessionid
, ccilog.orderid
, orderheader.userid
, users.emailaddress
, orderheader.webbrandcode
, orderitems.productcode
, orderitems.productname
, orderheader.datecreated
, ccilog.formattedpaymentdate
, orderheader.voucherpromotioncode
, orderheader.vouchercode
, orderheader.itemtotalsell
, orderheader.shippingtotalsell
, orderheader.totalbeforediscount
, orderheader.voucherdiscountvalue
, orderheader.totaldiscount
, orderheader.totalsell
, orderheader.totaltax
, orderheader.total
, orderitems.subtotal
, orderitems.discountvalue
, ccilog.amount 
FROM orderheader 
LEFT JOIN ccilog ON orderheader.id=ccilog.orderid 
LEFT JOIN orderitems ON ccilog.orderid=orderitems.orderid 
LEFT JOIN users ON orderheader.userid=users.id 
WHERE ccilog.formattedpaymentdate > "'.$datestart.'"'
```

I have a script that turns this query into a csv file. The whole script works great until I put in the where statement, an I don't get whaty I expect.

I have three rows that contain the dates greater than the start of the month date $datestart, but for some reason only 2 of them show and I just cant work out why?

My dates are setup in the same format is $datestart (eg 2011-07-07 13:31:28) and the 3 rows have the same dates but slightly different times, about 4 mins apart.

I'm stuck, can someone give me a bit of advice?

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the data:

```
---- Orderheader - 
row1 id:122
row2 id:123 
row3 id:124 

---- ccilog - 
Row1 orderid:122 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:23:52
Row2 orderid:123 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:28:24 
Row3 orderid:124 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:31:28
```

I'm sure that the type is a date type but can't work out how to see that for sure.

Comment: Could you please post the records which in your opinion should be output?

Comment: So, you definitely have three dates greater than $datestart in the column `ccilog.formattedpaymentdate`? What are they, out of interest? Do they definitely join to the `orderheader` table? The way you're adding the WHERE clause to the LEFT JOIN effectively turns it into an INNER JOIN (as you can never get any rows back where `ccilog.formattedpaymentdate` is NULL, which would be the point of the LEFT JOIN) but that shouldn't be causing your problem if you really do have three valid rows in `ccilog` that match your criteria.

Comment: The three dates are: 2011-07-07 13:23:52, 2011-07-07 13:28:24 <This shows ok, 2011-07-07 13:31:28 <This Shows ok

Comment: @Ben: the first and second date are less than `$datestart` you mentioned in your post.

Comment: @Quassnoi Looking at the code, that can't be what $startdate is set to. I guessed it was just an example of the format.

Comment: Yes sorry it was just an example (eg.) The start date is the start of the month. I'm thinking maybe I don't fully understand 'Joins'

Comment: Given what you've told us, I don't see how your problem is possible. Unless maybe the time on your PHP server is set wrong. What do you see if you `echo $datestart` after setting it?

Comment: I suppose it's also possible that the writing to the CSV file always writes one row less than it should :) But really I'm just guessing now, lacking the code.

Comment: echo $datestart gives me the start of the month as it should, I will check out your other theory but I think it's adds all lines it should

Answer (score 0):

Move your `WHERE` condition into the `ON` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN
        ccilog
ON      ccilog.orderid = orderheader.id
        AND ccilog.formattedpaymentdate > $datestart
```

`WHERE` is evaluated (logically) after the joins, so the filter gets applied to `NULL` values produced by the `LEFT JOIN` and the condition never holds.

Comment: This didn't seem to work, I just ended up with the entire table output.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem's really how you describe, then I'd guess that one of your three rows in `ccilog` that match your criteria has an `orderid` that doesn't have a corresponding `id` in the `orderheader` table (and if you wanted to include it, you'd really need a RIGHT JOIN between those tables, not a LEFT JOIN...)

Otherwise I'm with Quassnoi, as there's not much point in LEFT JOINing to a table and then specifiying WHERE criteria where a column in that table must be non-NULL.

Really, we'd need to see your data to figure out exactly what's going on -- at least the primary/foreign keys and the `formattedpaymentdate` column, including the types involved (if `formattedpaymentdate` is actually a date type column rather than a character column, for example, that could be confusing the issue.)

Comment: What is the easeist way for me to show you the data?, would you want table headings?

Comment: Table headings would be good, but we don't need all the columns. For the problem you're describing, start with `orderheader`, including just its `id` column, and `ccilog`, including just its `orderid` and `formattedpaymentdate` columns, for just the three rows (from each table) you believe should be showing up. Please also include the type of the formattedpaymentdate column.

Comment: Orderheader - row1 id:122 - row2 id:123 - row3 id:124 ---- ccilog - Row1 orderid:122 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:23:52 - Row2  orderid:123 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:28:24 - Row3 orderid:124 formattedpaymentdate:2011-07-07 13:31:28

I'm sure that the type is a date type but can't work out how to see that for sure

Comment: Also, it being a date type could certainly cause problems, but probably only in hours rather than in days (as timezones could come into the equation.) What are you using to query the database? Most of the standard tools (phpMySQLAdmin, for example) give you easy ways to examine the schema to find out data types...

Comment: Its Mysql query Browser on a windows server